# "requires body" warnings

Tags: compiler-warnings, ada

I have something like the following:

```vhdl
package ID_Count_Hashed_Map is new Ada.Containers.Hashed_Maps
  (Key_Type        => ID,
   Element_Type    => Count,
   Hash            => Hash,
   Equivalent_Keys => "=");
```

If I try to compile with `-gnatw.e`, I get warnings like:

> ```
> info: in instantiation at a-cohama.ads:73
> info: "ID_Count_Hashed_Map" requires body ("Has_Element" requires completion)
> info: in instantiation at a-cohama.ads:79
> info: "ID_Count_Hashed_Map" requires body ("=" requires completion)
> info: in instantiation at a-cohama.ads:90
> info: "ID_Count_Hashed_Map" requires body ("Capacity" requires completion)
> ...
> ```

What do these warnings mean? Where can I find about them in the documentation? And, if they don't relate to my code, how do I turn them off while still keeping the rest of `-gnatw.e`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably find the messages documented in the [GNAT User's Guide](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gnat_ugn/Warning-Message-Control.html#Warning-Message-Control)

Quoting from the guide:

> The use of this switch is not recommended for normal use.

The user's guide continues with an advice to use `-gnatwa` instead.